# Avoid using apps to send automated clicks

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a click game(Flutter) on play store and some of the users are using auto click apps to win all the games inside the app.

The problem is because of that users, my Admob account restricted. Because they are also clicking to the ads while they are playing. Google restricted my ads.

I blocked the emulators inside the app, with checking is it physical device or not.

Is there any way to block this click apps?

How can I prevent my apps from those clicks?

Thanks..

Comment: Maybe this might help you? [How to detect auto clicker app used by android user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772506/how-to-detect-auto-clicker-app-used-by-android-user)

Comment: Have you tried to enter a limit (time) quota for loading new ads? For interstitials, for example, you avoid that too many are loaded (and therefore clicked) in a short time (the option is present on AdMob in the ad unit).

Comment: In my game, there are 30 seconds game sessions on average. After each game I am showing an ad. The problem is the users which are using the auto clicker apps, they are even clicking on the ad. They need to click faster to win the game. That's why they don't care the time. For example, the game took 20 secs to play, but the auto clicker will be running for 25 seconds. Then in that 5 seconds there will be an ad and the user will click on it automatically. After this Admob is just limiting me.

Answer (score 0):

Make it impossible to win if users click more than a certain amount in a one minute period? Cobra (a really old atari game) did this for people who pirate their game. It works

Comment: But it's online for me, I cannot change anything in the game. I have to find a way to block those apps